# How to use Swift specific containers in containers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a Dictionary that holds another `Dictionary` that holds an `Array` which holds another `Array` of a custom class.  I'm having a lot of trouble working with these can someone who this comes easy to tell me the ways I can define, initialize, and access and assign to either part specifically.

```
Dic = [String: [String: [[MyClass]]]]
```

Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what part you are having trouble with. Can you provide more details? What does the data structure represent? Where is it stored? What modifications do you need to make?

Comment: what is the need/use case to compartmentalize the data like that?

Answer (score 1):

This code shows you how to do what you asked, but the data structure you requested is quiet cumbersome to use. I'll recommend to think again about what you want to accomplish and review this data structure.

```
class MyClass {
   var name : String
   init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
   }
}

// Create your dictionary
var dic : [String: [String: [[MyClass]]]] = [:]

// Create a list of MyClass object
var list = [MyClass(name: "first"), MyClass(name: "second"), MyClass(name: "third")]

// Create a dictionary with string key and array of array of type MyList
var myClassDic = ["test": [list]]

// update or add new value via the updateValue method
dic.updateValue(myClassDic, forKey: "index1")

// update or add new value via the subscript
dic["index2"] = ["test2": [[MyClass(name: "forth"), MyClass(name: "fith")]]]

// Iterate over your outer dictionairy
for key in dic.keys {
   // retrieve an entry from your outer dictionary
   var tempDic =  dic[key]
   // Iterate over your inner dictionary
   for sKey in tempDic!.keys {
       // retrieve an array of array of MyList Object
       var containerList = tempDic![sKey]
       // iterate over the outer array
       for listVal in containerList! {
           //Iterate over the inner array
           for sListVal in listVal {
               print("\(sListVal.name) ")
           }
           println()
       }
   }
}
```